# Odd behavior when implementing AES in C (convert char to bin)

Tags: c, aes

I'm implementing the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) in C. During the subBytes() step I'm having some problems on the conversion from char to binary.

With the code:

```
void subBytes(unsigned char* state) {
    int i=0;
    for(; i<=127; i++) {

        printf("%d",getBitState(state, i));

        if(i%32==0){printf("\n");}
        else if(i%8==0) {printf(",");}
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int getBitState(unsigned char* state, int i) {

    int bytePosition = i/8;
    int bitPosition = i%8;
    unsigned char byteValue = state[bytePosition];

    return  (byteValue >> (8-bitPosition)) & 1;
}
```

If the state matrix is:

```
50,   67,   246,   168,   
136,   90,   48,   141,   
49,   49,   152,   162,   
224,   55,   7,   52,
```

The output is:

```
00110010,01000010,11110110,10101000

10001000,01011010,00110000,10001100

00110000,00110000,10011000,10100010

11100000,00110110,00000110,0011010
```

So, as you can see, some values are well converted from char to binary but others don't. For example, the value 67 is converted in 01000010 (66). 
The only pattern that I see is that odd numbers are converted in even binary numbers.

Can anybody spot what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I hope this is just for fun. Please never use self-implemented encryption in production. There are implementations that are certified to have gotten it right.

Comment: I was about to say the same. [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) is a popular choice for a ready-made crypto library.

Comment: Yes, I know.. Is just for fun yeah (:

Comment: If you ask for bit position zero, you shift your byte by `8 - 0` bits.  I don't think your code is capable of checking that bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getBitState function can be reduced to the following:

```
int getBitState(unsigned char* state, int i)
{
    return !!((0x80 >> (i & 7)) & state[i >> 3]);
}
```

The double bang converts any nonzero value to 1.

Alternatively, since this is cryptography and speed is an issue, use a macro:

```
#define GETBITSTATE(state, i) (!!((0x80 >> (i & 7)) & state[i >> 3]))
```

[Here's an ideone.](http://ideone.com/N0g4Z6)

Answer (score 1):

8-bitPosition can never be zero, but you need it to be to get the bottom bit.